# Building LLVM on OS X 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: llvm, osx-yosemite

Does anyone have experience building LLVM from source on OS X 10.10 Yosemite? I am following this guide: [Getting Started](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html). I believe I have successfully built LLVM, but I am getting linking errors such as this (apparently related to linking):

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Google results seem to indicate that it could relate to stdlib being libc++ rather than libstdc++. I've tried those changes to no avail.

Sorry for the vagueness. Not expecting a miracle. Just taking a shot in the dark here. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I think you need to provide more detailed error messages; in principle libc++ should not be an issue since the builtin Apple Clang uses libc++ by default(`clang++ -E -x c++ /dev/null -v  2>&1 |grep stdlib`). BTW, have you tried building with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)?

Comment: And after you *built* LLVM, have you `make check-all` to ensure everything is working well?